# If $a$ and $b$ are positive rational numbers, why might we want to call the $√a$+$√b$ and $√a$-$√b$ are conjugates?

Tags: abstract-algebra, real-numbers

If $a$ and $b$ are positive rational numbers, why might we want to call the $√a$+$√b$ and $√a$-$√b$ are conjugate?

I know the definition of conjugates. Using that I can see this. What is the purpose of calling these two numbers as conjugates, that I don't know. How can I give the accurate answer for this question. Please help me. I am just the beginner in pure Mathematics.

Comment: What *is* the definition of conjugate?

Comment: In what context did you see them called conjugates (and only these two out of the four $\pm\sqrt{a}\pm\sqrt{b}\,$)?

Comment: Are you assuming additional conditions, such as $a$ and $b$ are not "perfect squares" (the squares of rational numbers), $a \ne b$ etc.? Otherwise I have no idea why you **would** call them conjugate. Take $a=0,\,b=1$. In what sense are $1$ and $-1$ "conjugate"? Same with $2 \sqrt{2}$ and $0$ - how are they "conjugate"?

Comment: @mathguy additive inverse is one such possibility for the pair you talked about.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee - sorry, I don't understand that. Possibility of what, exactly?

Comment: No, there is no assumption.

Comment: In algebra, the conjugate of a binomial is another binomial formed by negating the second term of original binomial. The conjugate of x + y is x − y, where x and y are real numbers. If y is imaginary, the process is termed complex conjugation: the complex conjugate of a + bi is a − bi, where a and b are real.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan - then I would say that statement is simply false (or, at best, "it makes no sense" - but "false" is more accurate).

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan - where did you come up with that definition of "conjugate"? I have a PhD in Algebra and taught PhD level (university) algebra and I have never seen that definition.

Comment: Hai. Math guy. it is a standard question

Comment: I got the definition from Wikipedia.

Comment: @mathguy I've never seen "*conjugate*" used that way, either, and I don't see what math sense it makes in that form. But it apparently made it on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(algebra)) so it must be "true"...

Comment: @mathguy for how -1 and 1 are conjugate. not to mix up conjugate and inverse, but in a conjugate you are adding an additive inverse instead of the value itself.

Comment: http://www.mathwords.com/c/conjugates.htm  https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/conjugate.html http://www.purplemath.com/modules/radicals4.htm  and likely more.

Comment: @Man That's not well-defined, e.g. $0 = 1-1$ has  conjugate $1+1$ vs. $0 = 2-2$ has conjugate $2+2$ $\quad $

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the numbers $a,b,ab$ are not perfect squares of rational numbers, the four numbers
$$\pm \sqrt{a} \pm\sqrt{b}$$
are indistinguishable algebraically over the rationals. More precisely, if one of them satisfies $f(x) = 0$ where $f$ is a polynomial in $x$ with rational coefficients, then so does the other.

More generally, if $K$ is a subfield of a field $L$, two elements $u,v \in L$ are called conjugates over $K$ if there exists nonzero $f \in K[x]$ (i.e., $f$ is a polynomial in $x$ with coefficients in $K$) such that

- $f(u) = f(v) = 0$.

  $f$ is irreducible over $K$ (i.e., $f$ cannot be expressed as $f=gh$ where $g,h \in K[x]$, and $g,h$ are non-constant).

Thus for example, the complex numbers $2+3i$ and $2-3i$ are conjugates over $\mathbb{R}$ since they both satisfy the polynomial $x^2-4x+13$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$.

Another example . . .

Let $L$ be the field over $\mathbb{R}$ generated by the expressions $\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)$ (i.e., $L = \mathbb{R}(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$, where $\theta$ is an indeterminate).

Let $K$ be the smallest subfield of $L$ such that $R \subset K$ and $\cos(\theta) \in K$ (i.e., $K = \mathbb{R}(\cos(\theta))$.

Then $1+\sin(\theta)$ and $1-\sin(\theta)$ are conjugates over $K$ since they both satisfy the polynomial $x^2 - 2x + \cos^2(\theta)$, which is irreducible over $K$.

Comment: That's correct, but then so are $-\sqrt{a} \pm \sqrt{b}$ which should all be called conjugates.

Comment: This is not even true in general (take $a=0,\,b=1,\,f(x) = x-1$).

Comment: I edited my answer so as to take into account comments by dxiv and mathguy.

Answer (score 1):

This is because $(\sqrt a + \sqrt b)(\sqrt a - \sqrt b) = a-b$. So multiplying those two irrational numbers gives a rational result. This is often a very useful step in algebraic manipulations such as "rationalising" the denominator (i.e. to make the denominator of a surd expression rational without changing the value of the whole expression). Hence the two irrational numbers are called conjugates.

This is analogous to complex numbers, where multiplying a complex number $a+bi$ by its conjugate $a-bi$ gives a real number, also a very useful step in complex number manipulation. Even though it's known by the same name, note that it's a different concept here (albeit related).

Comment: Then why x+1 and x-1 are called conjugates?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan You said you knew what the definition of conjugates, so perhaps it's good if you state the definition you're familiar with first.

Comment: In algebra, the conjugate of a binomial is another binomial formed by negating the second term of original binomial. The conjugate of x + y is x − y, where x and y are real numbers. If y is imaginary, the process is termed complex conjugation: the complex conjugate of a + bi is a − bi, where a and b are real.

Comment: I got the definition from wikipedia.

Comment: OK, I googled and also found those definitions: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/conjugate.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(algebra). Note that both those sources indicate that it's most useful in procedures like "rationalising the denominator" So while you can define an "algebraic conjugate" of $x+y$ as $x-y$, take note that it is useful only in some circumstances (like when dealing with sums of surds and in complex number manipulation), like I mentioned.